# ZF plus class-choice?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic

$\DeclareMathOperator\Cls{Cls}\newcommand{\ZFC}{\mathrm{ZFC}}$Let ZF be extended with class and set predicates, and extend the theory with a class abstraction schema so that for all formulas $\phi$:

$$\forall \vec{z}\;\exists Y\;(\Cls(Y)\wedge \forall x(x\in Y\leftrightarrow Set(x)\wedge\phi(\vec{z},x)))$$

Let us call the theory $\ZFC^{\Cls}$.

We know that many classes in $\ZFC^{\Cls}$ are proper classes, such as Russell's class $R=\{x|x\notin x\}$.

What happens if we instead of the usual axiom of choice have axioms which for any set
s, of nonempty non-overlapping sets, just postulate a *class* Y, which has precisely one member from each member of s?

For example, it seems clear that the Vitali set is not definable in $\ZFC^{\Cls}$.

Does $\ZFC^{\Cls}$ extend $\mathrm{ZF}$ in any interesting way?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar You are right. Thanks!

Comment: I presume you mean class variables, not class predicates, since you quantify over $Y$. Isn't the theory just equivalent to ZFC? (You haven't really spelled out the axioms of your theory regarding classes. But I expect the axioms to be arranged so that you can use Separation to separate a choice set from the choice class for $s$, and in the other direction, any choice set for $s$ should give you a choice class for $s$.)

Comment: @FarmerS, the exposition is incomplete, for example Extensinaity is not an axiom and also all axioms of ZF are relativized to the predicate $Set$, I think by using class and set predicates he actuay means a mono-sorted FIRST order language extended with two primitive one place predicate symbols $Cls; Set$ denoting "is a class" and "is a set" respectively. The question actually needs to be re-written by the author to clarify his intentions.

Comment: I think (not sure) that Randall Holmes's purported proof of Con(NF) uses a trick where choice is in some sense external. Notice that there is no known inconsistency with Quines ML + Class choice over sets, but of course it's inconsistent with Set choice

Comment: @Zuhair My exposition perhaps simplifed too much. As is usual, Set(x) is short for Ey( x\in y). Cls(x) is short for not-Set(x). The axiom (x)(Cls(x)) is presupposed.

Comment: @Zuhair “N otice that there is no known inconsistency with Quines ML + Class choice over sets, but of course it's inconsistent with Set choice.” May you point to literature?

Comment: I thought Cls(x) is short for x=x; and PropCls is short for "not-Set(x)"

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal, if ML is consistent then it has a countable model, and clearly this is externally well orderable, and so external (Class) choice holds, but of course the set world of ML is NF where choice is negated (Specker).

Comment: Zuhair Al-Johar No, the definitions are as I stated. My terminology is standard, for class-extensions. If I remember correctly, Gödel uses an equivalent notation in his Choice/Continuum paper.

Comment: @FrodeAlfsonBjørdal, you said that Cls(x) is short for "not-Set(x)". But this is NOT the standard definition, the standard is to take every object as a class, and only Proper classes as "non-Sets"

Comment: @Zuhair Al-Johar Yes, what I stated was slightly inaccurate. The best is to take all objects to be classes, and sets are those classes which are members in other classes: i. e. Set(x) <-> Ey(x\in y)